# Custom header using PHP soap functions

Tags: soap, soap-client, php

I am having a problem getting a custom soap header to work with PHP5. Can anybody guide me please.

What I require is something like this

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <USER>myusername</USER>
  <PASSWORD>mypassword</PASSWORD>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

What I get is :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <ns2:null>
    <USER>myusername</USER>
    <PASSWORD>mypassword</PASSWORD>
  </ns2:null>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

I would like to remove the namespace tags. 
The code I use to get this is:

```
class Authstuff {
  public $USER;
  public $PASSWORD;

  public function __construct($user, $pass) {
    $this->USER = $user;
    $this->PASSWORD = $pass;
  }
} 

$auth = new Authstuff('myusername', 'mypassword');
$param = array('Authstuff' => $auth);
$authvalues = new SoapVar($auth,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);

$header = new SoapHeader('http://soapinterop.org/echoheader/',"null",$authvalues);
```

---

Null doesn't seem to pass.. with 'null' I still get name space as in second example.. how to exclude this NS... thanks for your help in advance..

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = new SoapHeader(null, 'USER', $username);
$headers[] = new SoapHeader(null, 'PASSWORD', $password);

$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
try {
    $result = $client->getAvailableLicensedDNCount('ASX01');
    print_r($result);
```

> Fatal error: SoapHeader::SoapHeader(): Invalid parameters. Invalid namespace. in /usr/home/deepesh/SoapCalls/deepesh7.php on line 29

Answer (score 7):

I needed something similar and was able to use an XSD_ANYXML SoapVar to achieve this:

```
    $auth = "<username>$username</username>";
    $auth .= "<password>$password</password>";
    $auth_block = new SoapVar( $auth, XSD_ANYXML, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );

    $header = new SoapHeader( 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 'Header', $auth_block );
    $soap_client->__setSoapHeaders( $header );
```

This resulted in:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <username>12345</username>
   <password>12</password>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you are creating only one SoapHeader entry (with namespace, but named 'null'). Your desired result contains two separate header entries (without namespace), so you might try:

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = new SoapHeader(NULL, 'USER', $auth->USER);
$headers[] = new SoapHeader(NULL, 'PASSWORD', $auth->PASSWORD);
```

You'd then pass the `$headers` array to the soap call (either directly, or upfront via [`__setSoapHeaders`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php)).